# JavaScript Audio Spectrum Analyzer

Tags: javascript, audio, animation

Is there a JavaScript equivalent to ActionScript's `channel.leftPeak` or `channel.rightPeak`. This is used for sound programming such as for a VU meter. I am trying to build a sound application, but I was avoiding using Flash and ActionScript since it is for a website. I was wondering if it was possible to do it in JavaScript. The basic concept is just play a song and be able to see the visualization of it through the spectrum analyzer or VU Meter.

Comment: A VU meter is not an equalizer.  A spectrum analyzer is not an equalizer.

Comment: well thats my bad. But the idea is there, I want to create a graphic visualizer, but I want to avoid actionsript and use javascript instead. Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3761407/362536  Unfortunately, your options are very limited.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9516324/352796).

Comment: Just did a bit of browsing around, came back with the same answer as others here, doesn't look like it's entirely possible in all browsers/environments but here's some links that might help you get started for those that do offer support: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

Comment: Removed Flash Tag since you not looking for a flash solution and added animation tag instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need, based on your question, is [**JavaScript SoundManager2**](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) plugin.

The demo page for the **Spectrum Analyzer / VU Meter** visuals are [**HERE**](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/canvas-visualization.html)

**Screenshot:**
[image]

---

**Edit:** Also consider [**wavesurfer.js**](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) featuring ***"Seekable waveform using WebAudio and Canvas"***.